# Diplomatic Consequences of Events in Endless Space

Tags: endless-space

In *Endless Space*, I can choose reactions that are "Selfish", "Helpful" or "Hostile". The "Helpful" options often benefit other empires, while the "Hostile" options often hinder them.

**Do my choices have any affect on my diplomatic relationships with other empires?**

- Will they notice that I chose to take a hostile stance, perhaps
  reducing their research or production rate (for example)?
- Will they be more happy if I choose to give everyone a boost?

Answer (score 1):

- The answer is very likely no. In the diplomacy window there is a tool-tip how the your reputation is calculated when you mouse over a races avatar. It never changed due to my choices. Nor have I ever noticed the AI being influenced by the choice other than the stated effect. It's probably more a psychology experiment when playing against human player.
- Whether AI is happy about your choice is probably more a philosophical question. [Could a machine or an AI ever feel genuine human-like emotions?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14883/could-a-machine-or-an-ai-ever-feel-genuine-human-like-emotions)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. AFAIK the events don't have any effect apart from what you see on the choice screen (and the subsequent screens, if it's a multi-choice event, or one with consequences of some sort).

EDIT: if you don't mind spoilers, here are the exact consequences of each of the events: http://endlessspace.wikia.com/wiki/Random_Events#Interactive_Events. none of them seem to have any effect on diplomacy, except for one 'static' event (no choice to make here) which sets all faction relations to peace.